# HTML - button link inside a form

Tags: html, css

I am creating a login feature but I also need a register button. This register button has to be in the same form as the login feature because I need to display them in block.

or logging in but I also need a register button which redirects the user to another page. But since the form already has an action, how would I add a button to the form and still be able to redirect the user to another page?

Answer (score 2):

Instead

```
<button>
```

Use

```
<a class="btn btn-md btn-register" href="register.html">Register</a>
```

and put some css for **btn-register** to show it as button.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a button, you can do something like this:-

```
 <button onclick = "window.location.assign('https://example.com')">Register</button>
```